# Google Chart - Show Data Annotations on Points - Interactive Line Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I need to show data points on the line chart, i.e. which appear on mouse over at a point, i need them all displayed by default i.e. not by mouse over. Any clues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

```
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
```

and add one more value at the time of adding record with `data.addRows` of type string.

That will be shown just above the point on chart.

Thanks!

Comment: if that solution works for you, then could you please approve my answer and close this question ? 
:)

Comment: Not the original author, but much obliged.

Comment: Much obliged! I'm trying to do this as well, but with the data feeding from MySQL would you be able to help? array('label' => 'process_name', 'type' => 'string'), I have added array('label' => 'process_name', 'type' => 'string' 'role' => 'annotation') BUT it displayes the numbers BUT the line chart went away any thoughts?